# How to change the size of an object inside CollectionView Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I don't can change height of an object inside collectionView Xamarin, how to change height with c#?

Comment: Show your xaml, code?

Comment: Set a HeightRequest value on the layout container inside your template

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the control's height with your objects like:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
   <Button Text="{Binding btnText}"
HeightRequest="{Binding heightvalue}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```